# Setting a European country for billing in Google Workspace

Tags: google-workspace-for-business

Google Workspace become a paying service. Trying to register my company's address, the web page offered only US States, not general countries including European ones. Probably because I have a dot com domain name.

I have selected Alaska to make it work, but I would like to set my real country.

How can I do that? How can I make Google think that I am not a US company?